# Small red x instead of image in pdf when created with coldfusion

Tags: pdf, coldfusion

I'm trying to embed an image in a pdf using cfdocument, it looks like this:

```
FORM:  <input type="file" name="strFileName">

SUBMIT:
<cfset myImage=ImageNew(#Form.strFileName#)>

        <cfdocument format="PDF" overwrite="yes" filename = "#Form.strFileName#.pdf" >     
            <cfdocumentsection>  
                <cfimage source="#myImage#" action="writeToBrowser">
            </cfdocumentsection>
        </cfdocument>
```

If I use `<cfoutput><cfimage source="#myImage#" action="writeToBrowser"></cfoutput>` it will print the image to the browser, so I'm sure the image exists.

Comment: I don't think you can use cfimage within a cfdocument tag. Especially not streaming it with writeToBrowser. Try using a standard HTML img tag instead. The image src needs to be accessible via HTTP from your ColdFusion server.

Comment: This definitely works, I used it elsewhere with an image, the difference here is the image is uploaded. Is it possible the image isn't readable?

Comment: Try specifying UNC path for image; hopefully it will work.

Comment: *the difference here is the image is uploaded* Why do you believe that makes a difference? Exactly where is the image uploaded and how do you normally access it from the CF server?

Comment: It works with an image on the server and providing a path to that image in the cfimage tag. I'm going to try moving the image first, then using a UNC path.

Comment: There is no need to use a UNC path if the image is already on the local CF server.